# pyspark dataframe is giving an error with show()

Tags: apache-spark, hive, pyspark, apache-zeppelin, livy

I am using Zeppelin notebook with %livy.pyspark interpreter. I am running a SQL query on Hadoop Hive table and want to see few lines to the table. I am using below code:

```
'''
%livy.pyspark
from pyspark.sql import HiveContext
sqlContext = HiveContext(sc)
df = sqlContext.sql("Select * from Orders")
df.printSchema()
df.show()
'''
```

It is showing the table schema with df.printSchema(). However, giving following error with df.show()

```
'''An error occurred while calling showString.
: java.lang.RuntimeException: serious problem'''
```

Could you please help me to resolve this issue?

Comment: Here Orders table is a transaction table. show() is working on other table.

Answer (score 0):

This is the issue with HIVE(https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/HIVE-13120). Workaround is to set `set hive.fetch.task.conversion=none`